# Get items of all the pages of a paginator in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9, paginator

I am stuck with a part were I have some paginated data displayed and I want that data to be sorted  when I press on a button in Laravel 9 but the thing is that I can't find any ways to retrieve all the items of the paginator (I only get the items of the first page).

What I did:

I made a form that have a button that submits the form and triggers the sorting method in that form I added a hidden input that has as value the paginator instance in my Blade view.

This paginator instance has two pages each one have two items:

```php
$events = Event::where('endingAt', '>', Carbon::now('GMT+1'))->paginate(2);
```

To see it clearly here's a `dd` of that **$events** variable

```php
^ array:2 [▼
  0 => {#294 ▼
    +"id": 18
    +"title": "Gaming Hackathon"
    +"object": "This hackathon is a competition between different selected teams with an objective of building a full functional game in 3 days!!"
    +"startingAt": "2022-08-12 06:30:00"
    +"endingAt": "2022-08-14 21:00:00"
    +"location": "Kabukichō Ichiban-gai, Shinjuku, Tokyo, Japan"
    +"room": "III-5"
    +"created_at": "2022-08-11T11:07:47.000000Z"
    +"updated_at": "2022-08-11T11:07:47.000000Z"
  }
  1 => {#293 ▼
    +"id": 19
    +"title": "Soft Skills Course"
    +"object": "This event is a course available for our employees to further develop their soft skills and especially negotiation and communication skills"
    +"startingAt": "2022-08-12 09:00:00"
    +"endingAt": "2022-09-12 18:40:00"
    +"location": "11, Amdl Rabat, Rue Al Kayraouane , Hassan, Rabat, Morocco"
    +"room": "Open Space"
    +"created_at": "2022-08-11T11:10:30.000000Z"
    +"updated_at": "2022-08-11T11:10:30.000000Z"
  }
]
```

It only returns 2 items out of 4 which means that it only returns the paginator's first page's items. How can I make sure that I get the items of all the paginator's pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by pushing query results to the session before paginating them, I know it would hinder the website's performance but it's just a temporary fix, I guess I will create a temp table in the database and store/remove that data in it whenever I need.

That's the best solution I thought of, if you got a better solution please let me know :D

Answer (score 1):

if you want all the items you don't want to paginate so just call get instaed of paginate

```
$events = Event::where('endingAt', '>', Carbon::now('GMT+1'))->get();
```

Comment: The thing is that i already have the data in the paginator instance passed to the method, so there's no need to redo the query, i jut wanna access the elements of all the paginator's pages instead of only the first one, because I am implementing this for lots of views with large datasets so fetching all that data again will require me making some tests on the routes and re-fetching the data according to the route name which will kill the website's speed and performance

Comment: My understanding of Laravel paginator is that it will give you the number of pages and links to next, previous etc but only the full data of the page the user is on. I am doubtful that you already have all the data in the paginator instance.

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't find a way to retrieve all the data, so now I am trying to redo the queries based on the previous route

Comment: That sounds like a different issue. Maybe mark this as complete and create a new question with your route